# Vite - React app Uncaught Reference error

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, vite

I'm trying to deploy a static site developed with React, built with Vite and served with nginx in a container.

When I build the site in production mode and deploy it I'm getting an empty page and the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined
    at index-88887ec7.js:3920:212911
    at index-88887ec7.js:1:26
    at index-88887ec7.js:5196:49799
```

and the source:

```js
 });
    var _createClass$5 = function() {
        function _e(et, tt) {
            for (var rt = 0; rt < tt.length; rt++) {
                var nt = tt[rt];
                nt.enumerable = nt.enumerable || !1,
                nt.configurable = !0,
                "value"in nt && (nt.writable = !0),
                Object.defineProperty(et, nt.key, nt)
            }
        }
        return function(et, tt, rt) {
            return tt && _e(et.prototype, tt),
            rt && _e(et, rt),
            et
        }
    }()
      , _arguments = arguments
      , _react$8 = reactExports
      , _react2$8 = _interopRequireDefault$p(_react$8)
      , _propTypes$8 = propTypesExports
      , _propTypes2$8 = _interopRequireDefault$p(_propTypes$8);
    function _interopRequireDefault$p(_e) {
        return _e && _e.__esModule ? _e : {
            default: _e
        }
    }
```

When I serve the site locally with `vite preview` it's all working fine.

Here is my Vite config:

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default ({ mode }) => {
    const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), ['VITE_']);
    return defineConfig({
        define: {
            'process.env': env,
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': 'src',
            },
        },
        build: {
            outDir: 'build',
        },
        server: {
            open: true,
        },
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                scss: {
                    quietDeps: true,
                },
            },
        },
        plugins: [react(), svgr({ svgrOptions: { icon: true } }), viteTsconfigPaths()],
    });
};
```

and the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:20.10.0 as builder

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG SERVER_NAME
ARG BACKEND_URL

ARG VITE_APP_VERSION

COPY . ./

RUN cp .env.$ENVIRONMENT .env

RUN apt -y update && apt -y install gettext-base
RUN envsubst "\$SERVER_NAME \$BACKEND_URL" < nginx.conf.template > nginx.conf

RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install
RUN pnpm build

FROM nginx

EXPOSE 80

COPY --from=builder nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=builder /build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```